# conflict between mongoid and mongo (mongo-ruby-driver)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I need to use the two gems `mongoid` and `mongo` in my Rails app.

Any ideas to workaround this troublesome problem thanks~

```
gem 'mongo', '2.0.2',:git => 'git://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver.git'
gem 'mongoid', '4.0.0'
# gem "mongo_mapper"
```

### Error message

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bson":
  In Gemfile:
    mongo (= 2.0.2) ruby depends on
      bson (~> 3.0) ruby

    mongoid (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      moped (~> 2.0.0) ruby depends on
        bson (~> 2.2) ruby
```

### UPDATE

Mongoid is handy , but sometime it is sucks,

because I got error `'Client Error: Remaining data too small for BSON object`,

and  even I wrapped it in `begin rescue block` , it still break my Rails app, and stop the import data task, what the suck Mongoid is ! So I decided to give up use Mongoid to insert new records to collection , I tried to use  `mongo`. But they are conflict in my Rails app, WTH again !

```
  def bulk_insert_to_collection(collection_name)
    model = collection_name.capitalize.constantize.new
    begin
      model.collection.insert(@data_in_chunk)
      # @bulk.execute
    rescue Exception=>err  
      log_error "[#{err}] File #{@file_path}: line of #{i} #{Time.now}"
    rescue Exception => err
      log_error "[#{err}] File #{@file_path}: line of #{i} #{Time.now}"
    rescue => err
       p ex
      log_error "[#{err}] File #{@file_path}: line of #{i} #{Time.now}"
    end
    # @data_in_chunk = []
  end
```

Comment: Can you please describe the reason you want to use both gems at the same time? Maybe there's a solution to solve your problem with just one of them...

Comment: HI @oscar I updated my question, I tried to give up Mongoid now and the dependency conflict between Mongoid  and Mongo almost killed me.

Comment: Why don't you fix the "Remaining data too small for BSON object" error instead? Why are you trying to use that specific version of mongo?

Comment: @muistooshort the data is billions of records, and the error breaks all my importing tasks, and i can stop it break my whole task, even use `rescue`, I have no idea

Comment: @muistooshort I find no version of `mongo ` can compatible with `mongoid` could you suggest me better choice ?

Comment: Debug your data file and import process. You could start by looking at what is in `@data_in_chunk`. That error message comes from MongoDB itself, not Mongoid, not Moped, but the MongoDB server itself. You're trying to solve the wrong problem. You should be import data using the MongoDB CLI tools anyway, bulk importing through an ODM tends to be a pointless waste of time.

Comment: Hi @muistooshort is it possible to ignore the error from MongoDB server ? because the data contains millions of records, it's hard to debug it from source file.

Comment: To run into the bug within the parsing task, it takes my 10 hours, it's inefficient to reporduce the bug and try to find the incorrect data source.